# PHPMailer Error: Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, google-workspace

I'm using PHPMailer to send email and my code is working well with my personal gmail account, however, when I switch my personal email to my domain email, it's not working.

My domain email is hosted by G suit. And I have enabled 2-step validation and set up app password for both email.

The below is my code:

```
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               
  $mail->isSMTP();                                            
  $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                   
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
  $mail->Username   = 'xxxe@gmail.com'; //personal email                    
  $mail->Password   = 'xxx-personal-app-password'; //personal app passwrod                           
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Port       = 587;
```

This is working with my personal gmail account.

With my domain email, I only change the username and password to the domain email and domain gmail app password, but it's not working.

```
$mail->Username   = 'xxx@domain.com';//domain email                   
$mail->Password   = 'xxx-domain-app-password'; //domain app password
```

It show the error message:

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

And it only works if I login to G suit admin console and set "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" to "ON" rather than choose "disable access or allow users to manage their access". Is this because my app password wrong or Google thinks my app is not secure? If my app is not secure, why with my personal email, it's working?

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: If you google for something like "send gmail using php", you will get many many many posts/articles about this exact issue that will explain it in detail.

Comment: The problem is not my app cannot send gmail using php, the problem is it works with my personal gmail account, but not with my domain email hosted by G suit. My code is working fine with my personal gmail.

Answer (score 1):

> And it only works if I login to G suit admin console and set "Allow less secure apps" to "ON"

That is how it works.

I had similar issue once. ..

So instead of this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

try this instead:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do not want to turn on allow less secure apps.

Comment: @Moon - Then use their API instead where you authenticate/authorize yourself using OAuth. You probably need to register an app on their side as well though. You don't really have that many options. Google have made their accounts more and more secure.

Comment: It's not so much that gmail has made accounts more secure, it's that they have made them harder to use while keeping security about the same.

Answer (score 0):

With gmail, if you don't want to turn on "less secure apps" (which isn't really any less secure, but that's a separate topic), the only option is to use XOAUTH2 authentication. This is covered by PHPMailer's [examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps), [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2), and [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps) linked from error messages sends you there. There's too much to repost here.

Note that this is *not* the same as using Google's APIs. With XOAUTH2 you still get to use regular SMTP. Be warned though, like all OAuth implementations, it's extremely unpleasant to set up, is quite fragile, and poor feedback mechanisms mean you may have a hard time finding out if it stops working.

Comment: Why with my personal gmail email, I do not turn "less scure apps" on and it's working well, but not good for my domain email?

Comment: When I check Less secure app access on my personal gmail, it says "This setting is not available for accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled. Such accounts require an application-specific password for less secure apps access.", but the setting is different on G suit.

Comment: Google is inconsistent in enforcing the requirement (the official stance is that they are still transitioning), but gmail and gsuite have a number of differences, and this will be one of them. An app-specific pw should work ok.

Comment: No, the app password is working with personal gmail but not working with domain email. I don't know why...

Comment: You'll be much better off checking google's documentation for why that is and exactly what their rules are than asking here.